How to include Memcached
As the title says, I don't understand how to include the Memcached class. Installed from the official PHP Manual
 $mc = new Memcached();

$mc->addServer("localhost", 11211);



$mc->set("foo", "Hello!");

$mc->set("bar", "Memcached...");



$arr = array(

    $mc->get("foo"),

    $mc->get("bar")

);

var_dump($arr);die;

But I got an error:

Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found in
/var/www/html/api/invoices_list_full.php:32 Stack trace: #0 {main}
thrown in /var/www/html/api/invoices_list_full.php on line 32


If you run phpinfo() do you see the extension listed? (And make sure to run that from the SAPI you want to use, such as web or CLI.)

To use Memcached, you will need two things:

A Memcached server running (which most of time consists of a (small) executable/service running in background). For example Linux version or Windows version
The appropriate Memcached extension for your specific PHP (depending on the OS)

